# Why my Linux Mint 19 does not see my (Windows) NVMe drive?

Tags: linux-mint, disk, nvme

Hardware: Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming 7577, model number 7577-92774.

---

Question:

Why my Linux Mint 19 does not see my (Windows) NVMe drive?

I read on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive/NVMe#Installation):

> The Linux NVMe driver is natively included in the kernel since version 3.3. NVMe devices should show up under `/dev/nvme*`.

However, I have no device under `/dev/nvme*`.

---

Disk drives - Screenshot from Windows - Speccy Free:

[image: Speccy]

---

I have rebooted into Linux now, and am ready to investigate further.

---

I just installed `nvme-cli` package and this is its output:

```
$ nvme list

Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The culprit was in the RAID mode

If you switch, with special caution, to AHCI mode, it will show up in Linux.

The how-to switch to AHCI is out of scope of this site, refer to [my answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1359471/402107).

I am not sure why Windows requires that procedure, but I have read it on multiple places, so I believe it is necessary.

On the contrary, Linux does not need any preceding configuration.

---

Current status:

```
$ sudo nvme list

Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     Y7DF22FUFQCS         KXG50ZNV512G NVMe TOSHIBA 512GB          1         512,11  GB / 512,11  GB    512   B +  0 B   AADA4102
```